# vue-router not work with express

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting started with `vue-router`. Using `express` as server, but I found router don't work. The default page is 
[image: qq 20160218103211], 
when I change the view, it just show the orginal view, like this 
[image: qq 20160218103511]. 
if I restart the server, the view is work, 
[image: qq 20160218103356], 
but I can't get default page. This my project's address: [modern-java-web-scaffold](https://github.com/dolphineor/modern-java-web-scaffold/tree/master/frontend). Is there something wrong with me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That page makes me want to click `Greet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that in your server.js you had no calls to the express router. These are needed,  as Vue-router only connects to your vue components. This may be part of your problem.